# Problem on concept of continuity

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, functions, continuity, continued-fractions

If we draw a curve of a function without drop the pen then the function must be continuous or not?I am confused with it. If there is curve for which some portion of the curve parallel to y axis at any any x then there have many value for single x and we can draw this curve without drop the pen then the curve is continuous or not?[image]

Comment: This is not a function. The pen is going backwards, and like it can't go backwards, it can't go straight down

Comment: The vertical line can not be part of the graph (what you call the curve of a function) of any function (since that would mean that there are multiple $y$ values asigned to one $x$ value). If you would remove the vertical part (so that the drawn line becomes the graph of a function), then that function would not be continuous, since it has a jump where the vertical line was.

Comment: Because the definition of continuity of a function at a point x=a,                           lim f(x) as x tends to a from left side=lim f(x) as x tends to a from right side=f(a). But I also listen if you draw a curve without lift a pen the curve will be continuous. But in my question this two thing don't satisfy simultaneously

Comment: Thank you. Now it is clear. if for a single value of x there is many value of y it will not be a function. am I correct?

Comment: It is worth emphasizing as well that although this "pen never leaves the paper" idea might be a useful metaphor at times, it is not precise and it is not the definition.  There are examples of continuous functions which can not be drawn using this process and there are examples of pictures which are drawn which are not continuous functions (*as you have here since it was not a function (of x)*).  See a common counterexample: [Cantor Function ("The Devil's Staircase")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The curve you drew is not even a function curve .To talk about the continouity you should have a well defined function .A function is said to be well defined from $\mathbb R $ into $\mathbb R $ if and only if , $\forall x,y\in \mathbb R$ if $x=y$  then  $f(x)=f(y) $ which is not valid in your graph at $x=a$ .